# 3D rotation of a circle to make the edge cross two points

Tags: java, math, matrix, 3d, quaternions

I am trying to make a circle (actually a flat cylinder) rotate so that the edge crosses two points in world position. These two points can be anywhere on a sphere. The sphere has the same radius and position as the cylinder. the origin of both is [0,0,0].

It's a little bit hard to explain, so I included three pictures that I hope illustrates what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: flat cylinder with same origin as encapsulation sphere with rim touching two points]

Here you see what I am trying to accomplish. The yellow circle represents one of the points along the sphere, while the red circle represents the other point. The blue line is actually a flat cylinder going through the sphere, and is rotated so that it goes through both points.

[image: flat cylinder with same origin as encapsulation sphere with rim touching two points]

Here is another similar picture, but with the points at different locations.

[image: flat cylinder with same origin as encapsulation sphere with rim touching two points, the sphere is stripped away]

In this picture one can see the cylinder in full, as the sphere has been hidden.

**Now, I am really terrible at math, so I would really love an answer made up of pseudo code or a programming language. And if I should be so lucky, java.
The circles rotation can be represented with either a quaternion or a matrix**

So far, what I have tried, is rotating the cylinder with an up vector towards one of the points, and a forward vector towards the other point. But I can't seem to make it work. I have also tried other solutions, most of them involving two rotations (one for each point), but I end up having trouble when combining the rotations.

**Here is my current non-working code:**

This code makes the circle go through the first point, and then rotates it with an "up vector" towards the same point, this second rotation varies depending on the first point position, and is kind off all over the place.

```
//calculate direction vector between the two points
point1point2dir.set(point1Pos);
//subtract point two position
point1point2dir.sub(point2Pos);
//normalize
point1point2dir.nor();

//make two quaternions for rotation
Quaternion rot1=new Quaternion();
Quaternion rot2=new Quaternion();


//set first rotation two a rotation between X-axis and point1 position. Vector3.X = (1,0,0)
rot1.set(m.quatUtils.getRot(Vector3.X, point1Pos));

//crossmuliply direction vector between the two points with X-axis
point1point2dir.crs(Vector3.X);

//set the second rotation to a rotation between Z-Axis and the crossmultiplied direction vector
rot2.set(m.quatUtils.getRot(Vector3.Z, point1point2dir));

//multiply the two rotations
rot1.mul(rot2);

//apply the rotation to the cylinders matrix
cylinderMatrix.rotate(rot1);


//the function that gets the quaternion rotation between two vectors
Quaternion getRot(Vector3 pStart, Vector3 pDest) {
    start.set(pStart);
    dest.set(pDest);

    start.nor();
    dest.nor();

    cosTheta = Vector3.dot(start.x, start.y, start.z, dest.x, dest.y,
            dest.z);
    rotationAxis.set(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    if (cosTheta < -1.0f + 0.001f) {

        rotationAxis.set(Z_AXIS);
        rotationAxis.crs(start);

        if (rotationAxis.len2() < 0.01f) {
            rotationAxis.set(X_AXIS);
            rotationAxis.crs(start);
        }

        rotationAxis.nor();
        resultQuat.set(rotationAxis, 180.0f);
        return resultQuat;
    }

    rotationAxis.set(start);
    rotationAxis.crs(dest);

    s = (float) Math.sqrt((1 + cosTheta) * 2);
    invs = 1.0f / s;
    resultQuat.set(rotationAxis.x * invs, rotationAxis.y * invs,
            rotationAxis.z * invs, s * 0.5f);
    return resultQuat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this solution:

1. Calculate **v1** and **v2** as the vectors from the center of the sphere to each point that you want the cylinder to pass trough.
2. Cross product **v1** and **v2** to get the vector **up** of the cylinder, let's call it **n**.
3. Position the center of the cylinder in the center of the sphere.
4. Rotate the cylinder using **n** as vector **up**.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution! It was actually really simple. I don't know how I managed to bungle the math as much as I did earlier. I actually did spend alot of time on this >:)

**Sorry if I wasted anybodys time!**

The solution:

1. find direction vector from point1 **(A)** to point2 **(B)**.
2. crossmultiply direction vector with point2 to get **(C)**
3. Find the quaternion which represents the rotation from Z-axis to the crossmultiplied direction vector **(C)**, function for doing this included in the code attached to the question.
4. apply rotation.

Here is the working code (yay):

```
        //the rotation
    Quaternion rot=new Quaternion();

    //the direction from point1 to point 2 (the point positions are in this case also the direction vectors from center)
    point1point2dir.set(point1Pos);
    point1point2dir.sub(point2Pos);
    point1point2dir.nor();  
    //crossmultiplied with point2
    point1point2dir.crs(point2Pos); 

    //set the rotation to the rotation between Z-axis and the crossmultiplied direction between point 1 and 2
    rot.set(m.quatUtils.getRot(Vector3.Z, point1point2dir));    

    //apply rotation
    ekvatorMatrix.rotate(rot);
```

And here is the code for the function that returns the quaternion between two vectors:

```
    Quaternion getRot(Vector3 pStart, Vector3 pDest) {
    start.set(pStart);
    dest.set(pDest);

    start.nor();
    dest.nor();

    cosTheta = Vector3.dot(start.x, start.y, start.z, dest.x, dest.y,
            dest.z);
    rotationAxis.set(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    if (cosTheta < -1.0f + 0.001f) {

        rotationAxis.set(Z_AXIS);
        rotationAxis.crs(start);

        if (rotationAxis.len2() < 0.01f) {
            rotationAxis.set(X_AXIS);
            rotationAxis.crs(start);
        }

        rotationAxis.nor();
        resultQuat.set(rotationAxis, 180.0f);
        return resultQuat;
    }

    rotationAxis.set(start);
    rotationAxis.crs(dest);

    s = (float) Math.sqrt((1 + cosTheta) * 2);
    invs = 1.0f / s;
    resultQuat.set(rotationAxis.x * invs, rotationAxis.y * invs,
            rotationAxis.z * invs, s * 0.5f);
    return resultQuat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the initial cylinder is axis aligned with the "circle" ends in positive and negative X direction, and assuming cylinder and sphere is initially unit size (radius=1.0) I would do the following:

1. Convert the world coordinate representation of the Red and "Yellow" points (let's just for fun call them **A** and **B** shall we) to normalized vectors pointing from centre [0,0,0] (from now on called **C**)
2. Calculate the angle between **CA** and **CB** (which is really just between **A** and **B**). Let's call this angle **W**
3. Calculate the vector perpendicular to both **A** and **B** by doing a cross product. Lets call this new vector **D**.
4. Find the rotation matrix that rotates from [0,0,1] to **B**. Lets call this **M1**. This can be done in the same way as in point 3 (create a perpendicular vector and rotate identity matrix around it with the angle between the normalized vectors).
5. Find the rotation matrix that rotates **W** around **D**. Let's call this **M2**
6. Combine **M1** + **M2** into **M3**
7. You result is **M3**

This was not tested and so I don't know if it works.

Comment: This answer is really close to the solution. Good job!